# redirect http request to https on nginx server

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, nginx, safari

I am running an app on a digital ocean server using ubuntu 14.04 and nginx. My app runs via gunicorn. I would like to redirect http request directly to https. 
I tried

```
server {
    # Running port
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

and it works on safari. But it does not work on Chrome or Firefox? Any idea what I do wrong?
I attached the entire nginx.conf file below

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level   5;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   256;
    gzip_vary         on;

    # Configuration containing list of application servers
    upstream app_servers {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    # Configuration for Nginx
    server {
        # Running port
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        # Settings to serve static files
        location /static/  {

            # Example:
            # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
            root /var/www/example/app/;

            location ~*  \.(jpg|woff|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css)$ {
                expires 30d;
            }

            location ~*  \.(js)$ {
                expires 1d;
            }

            # we do not cache html, xml or json
            location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
                expires -1;
                # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
            }

            location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
                expires 30d;
            }
        }

        # Serve a static file (ex. favico)
        # outside /static directory
        location = /favico.ico  {

            root /app/favico.ico;
            gzip_static on;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        # Proxy connections to the application servers
        # app_servers
        location / {
            proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
            proxy_read_timeout 300s;
            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            # proxy_redirect http:// https://;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not serve anything on http. Everything should be on https, even `favico.ico`

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level   5;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   256;
    gzip_vary         on;

    # Configuration containing list of application servers
    upstream app_servers {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    # Configuration for Nginx
    server {
        # Running port
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        # Settings to serve static files
        location /static/  {

            # Example:
            # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
            root /var/www/example/app/;

            location ~*  \.(jpg|woff|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css)$ {
                expires 30d;
            }

            location ~*  \.(js)$ {
                expires 1d;
            }

            # we do not cache html, xml or json
            location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
                expires -1;
                # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
            }

            location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
                expires 30d;
            }
        }

        # Serve a static file (ex. favico)
        # outside /static directory
        location = /favico.ico  {

            root /app/favico.ico;
            gzip_static on;
        }

        # Proxy connections to the application servers
        # app_servers
        location / {
            proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
            proxy_read_timeout 300s;
            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            # proxy_redirect http:// https://;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Next when you test in chrome or any other browser, make sure to open a Private or a Incognito window.

Comment: ok so you suggest to put the static stuff below the listen 443 ssl statement... I tried that, but it still doesn't do what I want. It serves http and https, but I want to always redirect to https...

Comment: Please join this discussion room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152957/edirect-http-request-to-https-on-nginx-server